# Forward DNS service query to Consul inside container

Tags: dns, consul

I am trying to craft some setup to be able to resolve ***.service.consul** type of queries by the Consul DNS service running **inside** the container. I followed systemd-resolved section in [official documentation](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/consul/dns-forwarding)  for **systemd < 245**, and added iptables rules as described. I got one service running **consul.service.consul** that was registered and visible in UI. After querying it either via host or via dig on ports 53/8600 I got **NXDOMAIN**. Am I missing something ? Any suggestions are welcome

```
root@a:~# host consul.service.consul
Host consul.service.consul not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

EDIT: What I also want to avoid is adding --network=host parameter to minimize impact on current configuration and scripts

SOLVED: It took me a while, but I found the solution. The problem was Consul ACL that needs read service capability. If somebody is interested, this is what needs to be done:

```
cat > sread.hcl <<EOF

node_prefix "" {
  policy = "read"
}
service_prefix "" {
  policy = "read"
}
EOF

consul acl policy create -name service-read -rules @sread.hcl
consul acl token update -id anonymous -policy-name=service-read
```

Just check before if any policy is already attached to token id (which must exist, obviously). If so add -**merge-policies** to the last command. Hope that helps.